# Drawing the graph of cubic function

Tags: graphing-functions

How can I draw the graph of the function: $f(x)=x^3-3x+1$,that has 3 solutions, to determine the number of solutions contained in the interval: $[-2,2]$?

Comment: What sort of math do you have available to use?  Obviously finding the solutions to the cubic is probably not allowed, right? `;)`

Comment: Some brief graphing tips: (1) You can determine the number and approximate location of the $x$-intercepts by looking at where $y = x^3$ and $y = 3x - 1$ intersect. (Note that each of these can be easily sketched by hand.) (2) The dominate term is $x^{3},$ which tells you what the graph looks like for "large" negative values of $x$ and "large" positive values of $x.$ (3) When $x$ is close to $0,$ the graph resembles $y = -3x + 1.$ (4) Every cubic has two turning points or no turning points, and by now you should know which is the case for this cubic. **(continued)**

Comment: **(continuation)** (5) Note that $x^3 - 3x + 1 = x(x^2 - 3) + 1,$ so you can try graphing $y = x(x^2 - 3)$ (easy using sign charts; note there are three $x$-intercepts: $x = 0, \pm \sqrt{3}$), and then shift the graph vertically upward by $1$ unit.

Answer (score 1):

A good idea to get some overview is to compute a few values, i.e. 
$f(-2)= -8+6+1=-1$, 
$f(-1)= -1+3+1=3$, 
$f(0) = 1$,
$f(1) = 1-3+1=-1$,
$f(2) = 8-6+1=2$. The graph has to pas through the points $(-1,-1)$, $(-1,3)$, $(0,0)$, $(1,-1)$ and $(2,2)$. 
By the IVT this already shows that there is (at least) one root in $\left]-2,-1\right[$, one in $\left]0,1\right[$ and one in $\left]1,2\right[$. Since there cannot be more than three roots anyway, we have shown that all three roots are in $[-2,2]$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple polynomial, so it shouldn't be very difficult.

- First, find out its roots, that is the value where $f(x) = 0$. This can be done by trial-and-error, or algebraically solving it. Once you find out the roots, you know *where the graph will cut the x-axis!*
- Then differentiate the function to get another polynomial representing the function's *slope* at every point. Then find out the roots to $f'(x) = 0$, which will show you where the function has maximas and minimas.
  Now substituting the x-values over here, you can find the value of these extremas.
- Plugging in intermediate values between roots will also tell you where the graph has what sign.
- Finally, put in $x \rightarrow±\infty$ and see where the graph will end up.

You can verify your graph on sites like [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) or [GraphSketch](http://www.graphsketch.com).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the problem is I simply don't know how to solve this cubic equation, and find the points where the graph will cut the x-axis

Comment: See here: http://www.gbbservices.com/math/cubic.html :)